# Update model function on Backbone collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I created this function on the superclass for all my Backbone collections:

```
updateModel: function (_id, updateInfo) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.models.length; i++) {
        var model = this.models[i];
        if (String(model.get('_id')) == String(_id)) {
            model.set(updateInfo);
            break;
        }
    }
},
```

the purpose of the function is to simply update a model given the server-defined `_id` property.

Is the function I wrote useful? or should I simply use this instead:

```
collection.add(model, {merge: true});
```

Comment: why writing your function to achieve already implemented functionality

Comment: so you're saying that collection.add(model, {merge: true}); is basically identical?

Comment: yeah you can check documentation http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
updateModel: function (_id, updateInfo) {
    this.some(function (oneModelInfo) {
        if (_id == oneModelInfo._id) {
            oneModelInfo.set(updateInfo);
            return true;
        }
    });
},
```